# (C#) Compiling class at runtime and calling methods from original code

Tags: c#, runtime, dynamic-compilation

I'm trying to compile code at runtime in C#, then from the compiled code call a function or initialize a class which is defined in the original code. 
The code I currently have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;

namespace CTFGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string code = @"

using System;

namespace CTFGame
{
    public class MyPlayer
    {
        public static void Main ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(""Hello world"");
        }
        /*public void DoTurn ()
        {
            Program.SayHello();
        }*/
    }
}

";
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                string errors = "";
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    errors += string.Format("Error #{0}: {1}\n", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText);
                }
                Console.Write(errors);
            }
            else
            {
                Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
                Type program = assembly.GetType("CTFGame.MyPlayer");
                MethodInfo main = program.GetMethod("Main");
                main.Invoke(null, null);
            }
        }

        public static void SayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm awesome ><");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, Running the runtime loaded method 'Main' is a success, and the message "Hello world" is printed. The problem starts here: in the original code I have a method called "SayHello". I want to call this method from my runtime loaded code. 
If I uncomment the "DoTurn" method, a compiler error will show in runtime:

```
Error #CS0103: The name 'Program' does not exist in the current context
```

My question is - is this possible, and how? 
Putting the runtime loaded code in the same namespace doesn't help (and that makes sense), so what is the correct way to do that? 
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add a reference to your assembly.

Comment: Consider using Roslyn.

Comment: Perhaps you should think about getting your code to compile at all before trying to dynamically compile it.

Comment: @DavidL Already did it. The code compiles nicely.

Comment: Someone correct me if i am wrong, but what you're trying to do would seem to cause a circular dependency.  You're assembly that you compile on the fly doesn't know about the currently executing assembly, but you're trying to call a method on the current assembly from the compiled code.

Comment: @Jonesopolis In the current situation it doesn't. I don't think a circular dependency will be caused, because you don't make the original assembly get compiled again. Think of it as having class A, inside class A you initialize class B, and you pass the current instance of class A to the constructor of B so it knows you're there...

Comment: Thanks, @SLaks. You are in fact right. I added a reference to the current running assembly and it works like a charm. I'm going to post it as an answer so others can benefit from it.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a reference to the current assembly solved the problem:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;                
//The next line is the addition to the original code
parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```

---

More about: 
[Compiling c# at runtime with user defined functions](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime)